# How to return a message back from the content script after a message from the popup?

Tags: javascript, popup, firefox-addon, content-script, browser-extension

I'm sending a message to a content script in a browser extension that I'm making. I then need to have a value that the content script retrieves sent back to the popup. I know that the content script can find the value that I'm asking it for since it's printing when I `console.log` the value. However, I can't seem to make it return this value.

The basic setup I have for the code is as follows:

```js
// popup.js
valueOnWebpage = browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true})
        .then(updateLabelInPopup)
        .catch(printError);

function updateLabelInPopup(tabs) {
browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {command: "getValueFromWebpage"})
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log("Result: " + result); // this is logging `"Result: undefined"`
                document.getElementById("id-of-element-in-popup").innerHTML = result;
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log("ERROR: ", err);
            });

}
```

```js
// content_script.js
function getValueFromWebpage() {
    return document.getElementById("id-of-element-value-i-want").innerText;
}

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
    if (message.command === "getValueFromWebpage") {
        valueFromPage = getValueFromWebpage();
        console.log("Ran by message listener ", valueFromPage); // This is in fact logging what I want
        return valueFromPage; // I want this so that I can do something with it in the popup
    } else {
        return "Not a recognized command";
    }
});
```

Comment: What you are doing here is insecure (i.e. it will be considered a security violation). You are directly using webpage content as HTML in a elevated security context (i.e. in a page that is part of an extension, like a popup). While it is unlikely to cause a problem, due to the restrictions placed on popup content, you should not be using `.innerHTML = result` to display the data from your content script, which is derived from webpage content. Given that what you are asking the content script to send is text, you could resolve this by using `.textContent = result` instead.

Comment: @Makyen Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was returning the value as the result of the callback function. That doesn't get returned to the popup script! Duh! You have to pass it as a message to the popup script. For some reason I thought there was no message passing allowed from the content script to the popup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a promise from the listener, instead of a primitive value, for example:

```js
// content_script.js
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
    if (message.command === "getValueFromWebpage") {
        valueFromPage = getValueFromWebpage();
        return Promise.resolve(valueFromPage);
    } else {
        return "Not a recognized command";
    }
});
```

`Promise.resolve()` wraps the given value as a promise, so it helps you to return any primitive value synchronously from a listener.